# How to add a tex specific area after the nomenclature title starts?

Tags: glossaries, indexing, nomenclature

I'd like to write a text (and also a small table) directly after the title `nomenclature` (in my version: `Glossar`) and directly before the beginning of the nomenclature glossar list.

```
%% LyX 2.1.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[twoside,ngerman,fontsize=10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\synctex=-1
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{calc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{nomencl}
%
%%USER-Specific Commands
\usepackage[headsepline, ilines,automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings 
\clearscrplain 
\ihead[\headmark]{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\chead{}
\cfoot{}
%
\usepackage[colorlinks,pdfpagelabels,pdfstartview = FitH,bookmarksopen = true,bookmarksnumbered = true,linkcolor = black,plainpages = false,hypertexnames = false,citecolor = black] {hyperref}
%
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}
%
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{babel} 
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
%
\chapter*{Einleitung}
\subsubsection*{Technisches}
\subsubsection*{Spezifisches}
Heute ass eine Katze \index{Katze!Futter!Verbotenes} Schokolade. \nomenclature{Schokolade}{Ein Nahrungsmittel.}
%
\addpart{Anhang}
\pagestyle{empty} %ohne Seitenzahlen und Kolumnentitel
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossar} 
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Glossar}
\printnomenclature[2.5 cm]
%
\clearpage 
\phantomsection 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Stichwortverzeichnis} 
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\printindex
%
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\nompreamble` to add some thing between title and the actual entries. For example,

```
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{%
This is some additional text\par
\begin{tabular}{ll}\hline
Some text & Some again\\
Some text & Some again\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,ngerman,fontsize=10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
%
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{%
This is some additional text\par
\begin{tabular}{ll}\hline
Some text & Some again\\
Some text & Some again\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
%
\usepackage{babel}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
%
\chapter*{Einführung}
\subsubsection*{Technisches}
\subsubsection*{Spezifisches}
Heute ass eine Katze Schokolade. \nomenclature{Schokolade}{Ein Nahrungsmittel.}
%
\addpart{Anhang}
\pagestyle{empty} %ohne Seitenzahlen und Kolumnentitel
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossar}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Glossar}
\printnomenclature[2.5 cm]
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I compile the "Here is the code"-code with just changing utf8 to latin9 I don't get any glossar. Can you write your used code with the "Set of all Transmission lines." etc.?

Comment: @laminin: with `latin9` I don't get the glyphs correct. Are you sure that you need `latin9` instead of `utf8`? However, your MWE missed `\makenomenclature` and that creeped in to my code too. Now corrected,

Comment: @laminin I get in both cases. You have to run makeindex like `makeindex.exe -s nomencl.ist -t "yourfile.nlg" -o "yourfile.nls" "yourfile.nlo"  where yourfile is `yourfile.tex`. Did you?

Comment: With LyX I was able to obtain exactly what you posted. Thank you! (I deleted my comments)

Comment: By the way: If I exchange in \nomenclature{Schokolade}{Ein Nahrungsmittel.} the text "Ein Nahrungsmittel." by a text of 200 words from http://www.loremipsum.de/ I didn't get any index anymore. For my document I need to have several entries which are very long. Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: @laminin No, it doesn't accept par breaks and too many words. It deserves to be a separate question. Please start a new thread with the MWE.